# main() not running functions properly

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

```
def load():    
    global name
    global count
    global shares
    global pp
    global sp
    global commission
    name=input("Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")
    count =0
    while name != '-999':
        count=count+1
        shares=int(input("Enter number of shares: "))
        pp=float(input("Enter purchase price: "))
        sp=float(input("Enter selling price: "))
        commission=float(input("Enter commission: "))
        name=input("\nEnter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")

totalpr=0
def calc():
    global amount_paid
    global amount_sold
    global profit_loss
    global commission_paid_sale
    global commission_paid_purchase
    global totalpr
    amount_paid=shares*pp
    commission_paid_purchase=amount_paid*commission
    amount_sold=shares*sp
    commission_paid_sale=amount_sold*commission
    profit_loss=(amount_sold - commission_paid_sale) -(amount_paid + commission_paid_purchase)
    totalpr=totalpr+profit_loss

def display():
    print("\nStock Name:", name)
    print("Amount paid for the stock:       $",      format(amount_paid, '10,.2f'))
    print("Commission paid on the purchase: $", format(commission_paid_purchase, '10,.2f'))
    print("Amount the stock sold for:       $", format(amount_sold, '10,.2f'))
    print("Commission paid on the sale:     $", format(commission_paid_sale, '10,.2f'))
    print("Profit (or loss if negative):    $", format(profit_loss, '10,.2f'))

def main():
    load()
    calc()
    display()

main()

print("\nTotal Profit is $", format(totalpr, '10,.2f'))
```

I need the main(): to call load(),calc() and display() in that order. However, the program stops after load. The output will merely loop the load without calc or print.

I have been instructed specifically to NOT place calc() and display() in the while loop block, tempting as that may be. Also note, that solves the problem but that is not the solution I am specifically looking for.

What do I need to do to make this program work properly?

OUTPUT SHOULD LOOK LIKE THIS:

```
Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: APPLE
Enter number of shares: 10000
Enter purchase price: 400
Enter selling price: 800
Enter commission: 0.04

Stock Name: APPLE
Amount paid for the stock:       $ 4,000,000.00
Commission paid on the purchase: $ 160,000.00
Amount the stock sold for:       $ 8,000,000.00
Commission paid on the sale:     $ 320,000.00
Profit (or loss if negative):    $ 3,520,000.00

Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: FACEBOOK
Enter number of shares: 10000
Enter purchase price: 5
Enter selling price: 500
Enter commission: 0.04

Stock Name: FACEBOOK
Amount paid for the stock:       $  50,000.00
Commission paid on the purchase: $   2,000.00
Amount the stock sold for:       $ 5,000,000.00
Commission paid on the sale:     $ 200,000.00
Profit (or loss if negative):    $ 4,748,000.00

Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: -999
Total Profit is $ 14,260,000.00
```

HERE IS THE OUTPUT I AM GETTING(THAT I DO NOT WANT):

```
====== RESTART: C:\Users\Elsa\Desktop\Homework 3, Problem 1.py ======
Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: YAHOO!
Enter number of shares: 10000
Enter purchase price: 10
Enter selling price: 100
Enter commission: 0.04

Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: GOOGLE
Enter number of shares: 10000
Enter purchase price: 15
Enter selling price: 150
Enter commission: 0.03

Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: -999

Stock Name: -999
Amount paid for the stock:       $ 150,000.00
Commission paid on the purchase: $   4,500.00
Amount the stock sold for:       $ 1,500,000.00
Commission paid on the sale:     $  45,000.00
Profit (or loss if negative):    $ 1,300,500.00

Total Profit is $ 1,300,500.00
>>>
```

Comment: "I need the main(): to call load(),calc() and display() in that order." - and that's happening. Job's done, right? "However, the program stops after load." - no. No, it doesn't. Your output clearly shows it going on to `calc` and `display`.

Comment: It sounds like you've misunderstood your project requirements. Since you haven't actually told us your project requirements, we can't do much to help you.

Comment: Regardless of my novice articulation of the problem, I'd like it to look like the output sample that I provided. How do I get to that point without touching def main:()?

Comment: You can't, which is one of the reasons why it sounds like you've misunderstood the requirements.

Comment: My teacher specifically said that if I place load, calc, and display in main that it should work as I *want* it to. However it is not doing that.

Comment: I can't? Why is it impossible to achieve that output? I'm not following.

Comment: calc and display need to be inside some loop, if they're not each will only be run once. If you want a function to get called more than once, you put it inside a loop. Move ur while loop to main, something like: `while name != '-999': load(); calc(); display()`

Comment: With a `main` like yours, `load` happens, then `calc` happens, then `display` happens, then you're done. You want a cycle of loading data, doing calculations with it, and displaying the result. That requires a loop around the 3 functions.

Comment: Interesting. So I went ahead and tried your idea, but it's still looping the input without "showing" the calc and display.

Comment: Sounds like you've still got a loop in `load`. That loop is causing you to keep loading new data (and trashing the old) without entering `calc` or `display` until you get a -999. The `main` changes aren't the only changes you need to make.

Comment: @user2357112 so it seems like I need to move the while loop out properly and put it into main, am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the solution (one of many) you could probably take:

```
  def load():    
    shares=int(input("Enter number of shares: "))
    pp=float(input("Enter purchase price: "))
    sp=float(input("Enter selling price: "))
    commission=float(input("Enter commission: "))
    return shares, pp, sp, commission


def calc(totalpr, shares, pp, sp, commission):
    amount_paid=shares*pp
    commission_paid_purchase=amount_paid*commission
    amount_sold=shares*sp
    commission_paid_sale=amount_sold*commission
    profit_loss=(amount_sold - commission_paid_sale) -(amount_paid + commission_paid_purchase)
    totalpr=totalpr+profit_loss
    return (amount_paid, commission_paid_purchase, amount_sold,
            commission_paid_sale, profit_loss, totalpr)

def display(name, amount_paid, commission_paid_purchase, 
            amount_sold, commission_paid_sale, profit_loss):
    print("\nStock Name:", name)
    print("Amount paid for the stock:       $",      format(amount_paid, '10,.2f'))
    print("Commission paid on the purchase: $", format(commission_paid_purchase, '10,.2f'))
    print("Amount the stock sold for:       $", format(amount_sold, '10,.2f'))
    print("Commission paid on the sale:     $", format(commission_paid_sale, '10,.2f'))
    print("Profit (or loss if negative):    $", format(profit_loss, '10,.2f'))

def main():
    totalpr = 0
    name=input("Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")
    while name != '-999':
        shares, pp, sp, commission = load()
        am_paid, com_paid_purch, am_sold, \
        com_paid_sale, profit_loss, totalpr = calc(totalpr, shares, pp, sp, commission)
        display(name, am_paid, com_paid_purch, 
               am_sold, com_paid_sale, profit_loss)
        name=input("Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")
    return totalpr
totalpr = main()

print("\nTotal Profit is $", format(totalpr, '10,.2f'))
```